# HTML/CSS Submenu in block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a submenu in html/css. I already have a piece of code, but i would like to have a submenu in block below each menu item, but i can't figure out how to do it. Anyone would like to help?

```css
.mainmenu {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.mainmenu ul {
  width: 940px;
  ;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'swis721_btroman';
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(../img/01.png);
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}
.mainmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'swis721_btroman';
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  display: table-column;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}
.mainmenu ul li:first-child {
  background: none;
}
.mainmenu ul li a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 9px 0 9px 0;
  font-family: 'swis721_btroman';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #292F51;
}
.mainmenu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #292F51;
}
.mainmenu ul ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}
.mainmenu ul:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="operador chefe">
      <a href="#">operador chefe</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="safety">
      <a href="#">safety</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="security">
      <a href="#">security</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="atendimento">
      <a href="#">atendimento</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="apoio unidades comerciais">
      <a href="#">apoio unidades comerciais</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Right now, when i hove over a menu item, all the submenu items appear at once, and in inline-block, which is not what i want.

Comment: Please note that a simple [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+dropdown+navigation) would have been useful.

Comment: Thanks for your contest.When you're just an amateur, like me, perhaps a simple search isn't enough. My code is different from other pieces of code i've searched before, Anyway, i'm not looking for  someone to give me a complete correct code, but to tell me, what part of my code i could change to make it work as i want to.If i'm breaking the rules, for asking that, i apologize...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main problems here:

- First this selector `.mainmenu ul:hover ul` it's wrong since is showing all `ul` elements when you `hover` the main `ul`.

  Change to this:

  > .mainmenu li:hover > ul

  Making visible just the sub `ul` element inside a `li`.
- Also those submenus need to be `absolute` positioned so they don't disturb the layout of the upper menu:

  ```
  .mainmenu ul li {
    position:relative;
  }
  .mainmenu ul li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:10;
  }
  ```

#### Check this Snippet

```css
.mainmenu ul {
  padding:0;
  width: 940px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}
.mainmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  position:relative;
}
.mainmenu ul li a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 9px 0 9px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #292F51;
}
.mainmenu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #292F51;
}
.mainmenu ul li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:10;
}
.mainmenu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="operador chefe">
      <a href="#">operador chefe</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="safety">
      <a href="#">safety</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="security">
      <a href="#">security</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="atendimento">
      <a href="#">atendimento</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="apoio unidades comerciais">
      <a href="#">apoio unidades comerciais</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code is almost working, but now, it only opens the submenu when i hover over the first menu item "operador chefe". All the other items  aren't working when i hover over them.Also, the submenu appears in a inline block, and not in a block.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.
The most important rule is that when you hover a li it should show its child ul.

```css
.main-menu,
.sub-menu {
    font-size: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;

    font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.menu-item,
.sub-item {
    background: navy;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 80px;
    padding: 4px;
}

.menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.menu-item:hover,
.sub-item:hover {
    background: blue;
}

.menu-item:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="menu-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item">Item 2 (With sub-items!)
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="sub-item">Item 3</li>
            <li class="sub-item">Item 4</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li class="menu-item">Item 5</li>
    <li class="menu-item">Item 6 (With sub-items!)
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="sub-item">Item 7</li>
            <li class="sub-item">Item 8</li>
        </ul></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

> *I don't really like submenu coded from scratch (from zero). You can today create some menu "without" any CSS.*

*You can use **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)** class to realize menu like that*:
*http://jsfiddle.net/fm571dsd/4/*

**html:**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank">Logo</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">operador chefe</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">safety</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">security</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">atendimento</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">apoio unidades comerciais</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**js:**

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            event.stopPropagation(); 
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```